# Retrieving Customer Id from stripe to store in database

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe as a payment gateway for a site i designed. I have been able to create and charge customers however, I want to also store the customer ids in my database. How can i retrieve the customer id? here is my code snippet:

....

```
// Create a Customer
      $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
          'email' => $email,
          'card'  => $token,
          //'address_line1' =  $addr1 . " ". $addr2 . " ". $city . " " . " " .$country ,
          //'address_zip' = $postcode,
          'description' =>'Partnership' . " " . $fname . " " . $lname
      ));


      // Charge the Customer instead of the card
      $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
          'customer' => $customer->id,
          'amount'   => $amount,
          'currency' => 'gbp',
           "metadata" => array("order_id" => "6735")
      ));

     //retrieve customer id
     $customerId = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve($charge['customer']);
```

This is the error message I got:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: charge 

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest' with message 'Could not determine which URL to request: Stripe\Charge instance has invalid ID: ' in ....
 1. enter code here
```

Comment: How did you solve this? I need a little help with it

Answer (score 0):

After assigning the customer object to the `$customer` variable, you can access its ID via `$customer->id`. This is what you do already to pass the customer ID in the charge creation request.

You should do the same to save the ID in your database.